# Good book to learn lower levels of computers

Tags: assembly, computer-science

I'm very interested in CPU and RAM, but way beyond the normal level of interest.

I'd like to learn how memory and cpu's work especial on x86 and x64 processors. I'm due to embark on an assembly language course using NASM and want to get fully grounded before I start the course.

A book that goes into detail about the registers and what they are used for, and how the CPU uses the memory. Topics on real mode and protected mode memory, and flat and segmented memory models would be a great help!

Does anyone know of such books?

Comment: Did you try google? Or did you try to search anything here? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=assembly+guide

Comment: Yes. But there is an issue with credibility when using the internet. Who's to say what source is credible? A book that contains topics on memory and CPU would be self contained and allow me to take it around with me when I'm on the train to work, lunch breaks, at work, in bed etc.

Comment: How is this "way beyond the normal level of interest"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Inside the Machine**](http://nostarch.com/insidemachine.htm) by Jon Stokes is pretty good.

[image]

Comment: Purchased this book last night on PDF. Very good book so far.

Answer (score 9):

To understand the general hardware operations and the basics of internal computer architecture and organization the following are good.

- [Computer Architecture and Organization by John P. Hayes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070273553)
- [Computer Organization by Carl Hamacher, Zvonko Vranesic, Safwat Zaky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072320869).
- [Computer Organization and Architecture by William Stallings](http://williamstallings.com/COA6e.html)

But to understand the internal you need to be introduced to digital logic for that i think the following book is good.

- [Digital Logic and Computer Design by M. Morris Mano](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000S6JQO2)

For x86 architecture and related hardware and the real more, protected mode, programming and all the intel 8086, 80x86, Pentium I, II, III, and 4 basics i will tell you to have a look at:

- [The Intel Microprocessors 8086/8088, 80186/80188, 80286, 80386, 80486, Pentium, and Pentium Pro Processor Architecture, Programming, and Inter- facing
  by Barry B. Brey](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1324073.The_Intel_Microprocessors_8086_8088_80186_80188_80286_80386_80486_Pentium_and_Pentium_Pro_Processor_Architecture_Programming_and_Inter_facing)

And ofcourse internet is your friend.